# zsh: how to get back 'unexpanded' command

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

Zsh has a nice feature of expanding globs. For example, hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> turns `ls **/*.js` into

```
ls app/assets/javascripts/application.js vendor/assets/javascripts/Markdown.Converter.js
```

Is there a way to collapse it back to original glob version? Or should I just disable glob expanding?

The reason I want it, is that when I am in the middle of debugging a glob and I hit `Tab` just to double check something, there is no way to get back and complete the pattern. I have to start from scratch.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `undo` `zle` command. For example, bind it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>_</kbd>:

```
bindkey '^_' undo
```

From [`zshzle(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshzle):

```
undo (^_ ^Xu ^X^U) (unbound) (unbound)
       Incrementally undo the last text modification.

redo   Incrementally redo undone text modifications.
```

Comment: Awesome! And also useful beyond this particular use case. Thanks!

Comment: When I put this in my `.zshrc` and `exec zsh` it doesn't work, but when I type it in at the prompt it does... what am I missing?

Comment: @TomHale: I am not sure. You may be overloading it in your configuration files. Try listing the current definitions with `bindkey`.